# How can I exclude a sub-directory with a .dockerignore file

Tags: docker

I want to exclude a sub-directory using a `.dockerignore` file, but I don't know what the syntax should be, and there are no examples anywhere.

I have a sub-directory `vendor/bundle`.

I've put

`vendor/bundle` in the `.dockerignore` file. Also `vendor/bundle/` and `/vendor/bundle` but none of them seem to work.

(Also, the `.dockerignore` file is being found, but just not working.)

Comment: have you tried the complete path, something like /abc/def/vendor/bundle ?

Comment: well, forget what I said, if the directory vendor is in the directory where your .dockerignore and Dockerfile are, just `vendor/bundle` should be correct, here is an example https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/master/.dockerignore

Comment: it's supposed to be from the root of the directory of the `Dockerfile`. So in that context `/vendor/bundle` would be the complete path. I tried all the way to the root of my file system `/Users/me/projects/myproject/vendor/bundle`, and that doesn't work. I've tried `vendor/bundle/*` but that only get's the next layer down, not the full contents of the sub-directories below.

Comment: in your .dockerignore, if you have several lines, the newline is a Unix or Windows one ? It neds to be a Unix newline.

Comment: Anyway, the doc sucks, lacks examples of correct and not correct .gitignore

Comment: This is my current workaround, but it's horrible: put in all possible variations, in reverse order (and one line at a time): `vendor/bundle/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*
vendor/bundle/*/*/*/*/*/*/*
vendor/bundle/*/*/*/*/*/*
vendor/bundle/*/*/*/*/*
vendor/bundle/*/*/*/*
vendor/bundle/*/*/*
vendor/bundle/*/*
vendor/bundle/*
vendor/bundle`

Comment: Lines are definitely Unix, since I'm on a mac. And when I run `docker build -D` I see it picking up the rules.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82258/discussion-between-user2915097-and-lukas-oberhuber).

Answer (score 88, accepted):

There is a shorter and easier method to write your `.dockerignore` :

```
vendor/bundle/**/*
vendor/bundle
```

Comment: Could you explain why both lines are needed?

Comment: because first line does not match the root of the folder vendor/bundle and its files.

Comment: Why is `vendor/bundle` not the only one that is needed? This totally departs from the `.gitignore` style that was intended of `.dockerignore`

Comment: It seems that use simply `vendor/bundle` will do now. I just tested and it works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of PHPStorm - Click right on project -> then you have an option ".i*" -> then select .dockerignore. It will ask you what type of project you have. I search for symfony PHP in my case. Then it will automatically create a template with all the files that need to be excluded.

After this project seemed to be working more efficiently :)!